# How do I set a pointer to Null at run-time (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, null

Right now I have a pointer set to a row in my 2D array.  I want that pointer to stop pointing to that row, but I will be using the pointer later for something else.  I just want to know how to unset the pointer after it is initialized and has pointed to a row.

```
double* tempRow;
tempRow = (double*) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
   ...
tempRow = NULL;
```

doesn't unlink the tempRow variable from the array row.  Why not?

I wonder if I should be using C then instead.  Will there be overhead when using a vector?

Comment: So, which book are you learning from? This is terrible C++ code, to be blunt, and covered by any [introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You should pick one up so you can learn C++. The answer, of course, is to use `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: -1 for "doesn't seem to work."

Comment: doesn't seem to work was referring to the sentence above the code.  ie Using the provided code "to unset the pointer after it is initialized and has pointed to a row ... doesn't seem to work."

Comment: Okay, so what did happen?  What did you do, and what, exactly, did you observe?  What do you mean by "unlink", or "array row"?

Answer (score 11):

While you have written will set tempRow to NULL, it wont release the memory you have allocated. For that you need

```
free(tempRow);
tempRow = NULL;
```

However if you're using C++ as the tags suggest, you'd be better off using C++ new/delete

```
double* tempRow;
tempRow = new double[size];
   ...
delete [] tempRow;
tempRow = NULL;
```

you can even use the STL to handle your memory allocation for you.

```
std::vector<double> tempRow(size);
// You can access the data, in a similar way to an array
tempRow[5] = tempRow[4]+tempRow[3];

// If you really need to access the underlying pointer, (To pass to another 
// function for example) you can do this. Note that the pointer will be valid
// until the vector is destroyed or modified in certain ways that can cause the
// vector to reallocate its memory. So you can't use this to pass data to a 
// function that destroys or takes ownership of the passed in pointer.

fn_requiring_pointer( &temp[0] );

// The memory used in tempRow will get cleaned up automatically when the 
// object goes out of scope
//
// If I really need to free up the memory used in it early I can use a swap 
// hack. (iirc tempRow.clear() isn't guaranteed to release the memory)
std::vector<double>().swap(tempRow); // Unneeded in most cases.
```

Also trying to reuse the tempRow pointer for something unrelated is probably not necessary. Just create a new pointer with a different name. Reusing a variable form multiple different unrelated purposes can make code very hard to understand later.

Comment: I've been told that `std::vector<double> tempRow(size)` is a good alternative to using `new[]` and `delete[]`, but I'm a C++ noob, so take that advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: Agreed std::vector<double> is often even better, if you dont really need the pointer. Added to the reply.

Comment: @ dreamlax That is a good advice, since the vector takes care of memory handling.

Comment: @dreamlax: I initially read that as you taking the advice with a grain of salt, and thought "if you're a noob, why wouldn't you believe some advice?" :-).  Now with you.  Good advice that ;_)

Comment: @Michael:  If you need the pointer, `&temprow[0]` will give it to you.  That's an old-fashioned array pointer.

Comment: +1 for std::vector<double>, and explaining him the two other ways.

Comment: @David Thornley - agreed, thats a good point. Added an example and implications to the example.

Answer (score 6):

I'm new at C++ as well, but a while ago, someone told me that using `std::vector` is a much safer approach to handling arrays of data.

- Automatic re-allocation when adding more elements.
- Iterators for use with stuff from `#include <algorithm>`.
- Bounds-protection with `.at(index)` element access.
- No messy pointer-tracking required.
- C-array style access with `operator[]`.
- RAII.

You would declare a vector like this:

```
std::vector<double> tempRow(size);

tempRow[0] = 3.00;
tempRow[1] = 1.00;

// no need to use delete[] or free(), it will destruct itself
// and relinquish its resources automatically.
```

Answer (score 4):

> Doesn't seem to work?

That's the worst complaint and a solution providers's nightmare.

Do you mean you get a compilation error?

If yes, did you include `<cstdio>?` and `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 4):

The example you've shown should work.
Also *if* you've not freed the memory before making `temRow` `NULL`, you are ***leaking*** memory.

```
double* tempRow;
tempRow = (double*) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
   ...
free(tempRow);  // free the memory.
tempRow = NULL; // reset the pointer.
   ...
tempRow = &some_other_double_var; // reuse the pointer.
```

Comment: I don't understand a lot about memory allocation.  Doesn't free just unallocate the memory?  Because that is not what I want.  I wish to reuse the memory later in the program.  I could free and set to NULL but then I'd have to reallocate the pointer every time I want to use it and I would rather avoid the overhead.  Perhaps I misunderstand because in your example you are freeing, setting to NULL and then reusing it without a malloc call.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Stuart: When you set the pointer to `NULL` and you don't want to call free, you need to ensure that there is another way to get to the memory allocated. Say you might have another pointer pointing to it. In case if you don't have such a way, you are leaking memory, that is there is no way to get to that memory let aside freeing it.

Comment: @Stuart:  It's hard to understand what you're asking.  `free()` deallocates the memory.  If you want to keep the memory for later reuse, you need to keep a pointer to it.  If you do `tempRow = NULL;` without `free(tempRow);` first, you've got the worst of both:  unreusable memory that can't even be reallocated.  BTW, you'd likely do better just `free`ing the memory and getting new memory later.  The overhead is unlikely to be that bad, and you don't appear to be comfortable with memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work in what way? The normal way to "unset" a pointer in C++ is with:

```
tempRow = 0;
```

but what you have should be fine, assuming you've included the correct headers or otherwise have the correct definition for `NULL`.

As an aside, you should first call `free()` on that memory before losing the pointer, otherwise you'l have a memory leak (and this is assuming you have a good reason to use C-style `malloc/free` instead of the more kosher C++ `new/delete`).